# How does Deno.run "echo hello" cause this file not found error?

Tags: typescript, deno

Trying out Deno's standard library, I ran into a problem with [`Deno.run`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.run) - a function to spawn a new subprocess.

This example is provided in the documentation:

```
const p = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["echo", "hello"],
});
```

Running this using the `--allow-run` permission, I get the following error:

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.run ($deno$/ops/process.ts:41:10)
    at Object.run ($deno$/process.ts:118:15)
    at file:///C:/Users/.../gitgraph-deno/gitgraph.ts:1:16
```

[js/process.ts:118:15](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/6feca0ef8bec69f4940c28a9ac0b6a0eeb6884ba/cli/js/process.ts) is a call to `run` in [js/ops/process.ts](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/6feca0ef8bec69f4940c28a9ac0b6a0eeb6884ba/cli/js/ops/process.ts), which itself calls `sendSync` in [dispatch_json.ts](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/6feca0ef8bec69f4940c28a9ac0b6a0eeb6884ba/cli/js/ops/dispatch_json.ts).

The stacktrace says the error originates from dispatch_json.ts line 72. This just unwraps the JSON response received in line 67: `const resUi8 = core.dispatch(opId, argsUi8, zeroCopy);`.

I think the `core.dispatch` goes all the way to [isolate.rs](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/36fde75d779078118af3b2b6c078bcbfb47b1a0f/core/isolate.rs) line 358. That's where I get lost.

**TLDR**: Somewhere under the hood of Deno this error occurs: `The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)` when I try to `Deno.run({cmd: ["echo", "hello"]});`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [posted below by Andrew Dibble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030688/13622492): Deno is unable to locate a binary file called `echo` in my path.
Google brought me to an [SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/1084354) telling me `echo` in Windows is just a [command internal to CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html). It's not a binary file.

`cmd /c` allows you to call CMD.exe's internal and external commands.

Taking that into account, I fixed my issue by using:

`Deno.run({cmd: ["cmd", "/c", "echo", "hello"]});`

Instead of:

`Deno.run({cmd: ["echo", "hello"]});`

---

And here's an example to also read the output:

```
const p = Deno.run({cmd: ["cmd", "/c", "echo", "hello"], stdout: "piped"});
const output = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(await p.output());
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deno is unable to locate a binary file called `echo` in your path:

```sh
$ deno
Deno 1.0.0
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> Deno.run({
    cmd: ["echo", "hello"],
hello
Process { rid: 4, pid: 24264 }
```

On my Linux machine, the above works fine because I have a program accessible in my path by the name of `echo`.

I do not however have any program by the name of `foo`:

```sh
> Deno.run({
    cmd: ["foo", "hello"],
});
Uncaught NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.run ($deno$/ops/process.ts:45:10)
    at Object.run ($deno$/process.ts:118:15)
    at <unknown>:1:6
    at evaluate ($deno$/repl.ts:45:34)
    at Object.replLoop ($deno$/repl.ts:136:13)
```

So when I tell Deno to run a program by the name of `foo`, it is unsurprisingly unable to find where this program lives and start it in a new process.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this in your particular instance because it's very setup specific, but I believe that to be the issue.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/1084354) says `echo` in Windows is not a program but a command, part of cmd.exe. Perhaps this is why Deno doesn't have access to it?

Comment: Echo being a command internal to cmd **was** the problem!
`Deno.run({cmd: ["cmd", "/c", "echo", "hello"]});` works just fine.